# Python Sockets Bind to 2 out of 3 network interfaces

Tags: python, sockets

When binding to a socket in python the value for host can be '' which means all interfaces. Or it can be a string containing a real ip address eg '192.168.1.5'.

So its possible to bind to all or 1 interface.

What if I have 3 interfaces and I  want to bind to only 2 of them.

Is this possible?

What value do I give host, I have tired a list, a tuple, a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to bind to the subset of interfaces using `socket` module. This module provides access to BSD socket interface, which allow to specify only single address while binding. For this single address a special value of `INADDR_ANY` in C exists to allow for binding to all interfaces (Python translates empty string to this value).

If you want to bind to more than one, but not all, interfaces using `socket` module, you'll need to create multiple sockets.

Comment: Thanks I thought that might be the case.